# Counting the number of DQ errors where conditions hold and creating a resulting table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy-slicing

I'm still trying to find my self around Python. I am doing a Data Quality project, where I am now trying to count the number of errors, while using certain rules to effect this. When I use the code to calculate the total number of error results I get the same answer (57) even though it's different rules/conditions.

```
'''tax_no_acc = dqa_proc_df.loc[(dqa_proc_df['KI_2204991'] == '') & (dqa_proc_df['KI_2205156'] != 'Blocked for both') & (dqa_proc_df['KI_2205157'] != '299005215') & (dqa_proc_df['KI_2205132'] != 'Yes')].count()'''
```

'''vat_no_compl = dqa_proc_df.loc[(dqa_proc_df['KI_2204994'] == 'Yes') & dqa_proc_df['KI_2205156'] != 'Blocked for both') & (dqa_proc_df['KI_2205157'] != '299005215') & (dqa_proc_df['KI_2205132'] != 'Yes') & dqa_proc_df['KI_2204995'] == ""].count() #vat_no_compl.count() NOT giving a single number'''

Please assist me on how I can get the correct results?

Thanking you in advance.

Regards,
Siyabonga

thanking you in advance.

Comment: I want to count the errors and put all in table for client report. data is in a tabular df format, where I can code rulest. I have tried: w: '''KI_2204992_type = ['0','1','2','3','9'],rule = dqa_proc_df.loc[(dqa_proc_df['KI_2204991'] == 'Yes')&(dqa_proc_df['KI_2205156'] != 'Blocked for both')&(dqa_proc_df['KI_2205157'] != 'ZPFO - Foreign Vendors - 299005215')&(dqa_proc_df['KI_2205132'] != 'Yes')&(dqa_proc_df['KI_2204992'].str.len() != 10)& (dqa_proc_df['KI_2204992'].isnull()) &dqa_proc_df['KI_2204992'].str.slice(0,1).isin(KI_2204992_type)].count()'''

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to understand what your problem is.
I would suggest you to reformulate it more clearly:

- What do you want to achieve?
- What does your data looks like?
- What have you tried?
  I also suggest to leverage the "code formatting options from StackOverflow.

From what I understand, its looks like you're applying twice the `.count()` method. You could try

```py
vat_no_compl = dqa_proc_df.loc[
    (dqa_proc_df['KI_2204994'] == 'Yes')
    & dqa_proc_df['KI_2205156'] != 'Blocked for both')
    & (dqa_proc_df['KI_2205157'] != '299005215')
    & (dqa_proc_df['KI_2205132'] != 'Yes')
    & (dqa_proc_df['KI_2204995'] == "")
]
print(vat_no_compl.count())
```